# From XAML builds to the vNext build system

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a list of heavily customized XAML build templates together with custom build activities written in C#.
I'd like to upgrade them to the new build system of TFS2015.

Which would be the best way to accomplish this?
Is there an easy way to reuse the custom build activities?

Comment: hey @ds19 have you figured out a way to move custom xaml templates?

Comment: @Taran the best solution is to make custom build tasks and incorporate the C# logic in the PowerShell scripts of the build tasks

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any reference you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use maybe some power shell to call c# code that you have. Rather not easy way not fully knowing customization's. So rather not some app that will do it auto for you.